# Do jquery functions & normal javascript code execute in sequence?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is the JS code I'm facing issues with:-

```
function clearPgnBtnsAndInfo() {
    document.getElementById("lblFromRecNo").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("lblToRecNo").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("lblTotalRecords").innerHTML="";
    $("#topPgnBtnsDiv").empty(); //removing all the child elements within the div
}

function resetSrchRptDataBtns() {
    document.searchForm.btnView.disabled=false;
    document.searchForm.btnEdit.disabled=false;
    document.searchForm.btnViewSPDet.disabled=false;
    document.searchForm.btnExp2XLSorPDF.disabled=false;
    document.searchForm.btnViewVer.disabled=false;
}

function doSearch(strReqSrcn,strSearchType) { // This function is called on press of a btn on the UI
    closeAlertMsg(); //close error msg if in page DOM
    clearPgnBtnsAndInfo();
    resetSrchRptDataBtns();
    if(strSearchType) 
    {
        var searchFormBean = new SearchFormBean(strSearchType,.,.,.,..); // Building the formBean
        $.ajax({
            url: strThisAppUrl+"/search/getSearchData.do",
            data: JSON.stringify(searchFormBean),
            dataType: "json", 
            contentType: "application/json",
            mimeType: "application/json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(responseData){
                if(responseData && responseData.searchResult && "success"===responseData.searchResult && responseData.searchResults){
                    var srchListData = responseData.searchResults;
                    var srchListDataTbl = document.getElementById('searchDataTbl');
                    currentSrchListData=srchListData;

                    $("#searchDataTbl").find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); //removing all the table rows except the HEADER row
                    writeSrchDataRpt(srchListData,srchListDataTbl);

                    //--[start] writing the Pagination Info & Buttons --
                    document.getElementById("lblFromRecNo").innerHTML=responseData.fromRecNo;
                    document.searchForm.fromRecNo.value=responseData.fromRecNo;
                    document.getElementById("lblToRecNo").innerHTML=responseData.toRecNo;
                    document.searchForm.toRecNo.value=responseData.toRecNo;
                    document.getElementById("lblTotalRecords").innerHTML=responseData.totalRecords;
                    document.searchForm.totalRecords.value=responseData.totalRecords;

                    var pgnTopBtnsDiv = document.getElementById("topPgnBtnsDiv"); 

                    //JS Code to build & append 4 Pagination Btns to DOM
                    //FIRST-Set Btn                             
                    //PREVIOUS-set Btn
                    //NEXT-set Btn
                    //LAST-set Btn
                    dismissLoadingSpinner();
                }
                else {
                        toggleSrchResultDiv("divHide");
                        dismissLoadingSpinner();
                        showTheMessage("danger",responseData.searchResultMsg);
                    }
                },
                error:function(data,status,er) {
                    toggleSrchResultDiv("divHide");
                    dismissLoadingSpinner();
                    showTheMessage("danger","Error in search request.");
                }
            });
        //--
    }
}
```

jQuery Version : 1.11.3

In mozilla firefox & chrome (have not tested in IE) the jquery ajax request is processed before the complete execution of the line `$("#topPgnBtnsDiv").empty();` in the `clearPgnBtnsAndInfo()` function.

Is there any bug in jQuery's `.empty()` function or can the jquery call be mixed with normal JS code before that line?

In JavaScript is it guaranteed when the `doSearch(..,..)` function is called - the function `closeAlertMsg();` is executed first, then the function  `clearPgnBtnsAndInfo();` is executed, then the function `resetSrchRptDataBtns();` is executed before the jquery ajax request code is called or since it is an ajax request it does not wait for the code above it to complete?

Are javascript functions called in sequence synchronous i.e, one does not execute before the completion of the other?

GIF animation of my problem :-
[image]

Comment: _"In mozilla firefox the jquery ajax request is processed before the complete execution of the line `$("#topPgnBtnsDiv").empty();` in the `clearPgnBtnsAndInfo()` function."_ Can you create a stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net, or plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Working code snippet cannot be created as of now as it is DB driven & the data is private. Attached is the gif image of my problem. The pagination buttons should be removed & recreated in JS code on each click of **Approve** button after selecting a record from the result area. But somehow before the buttons are removed (they are the child elements of the `div` element with id `topPgnBtnsDiv`) the ajax query is executed and the data & the new buttons are appended to the result area.

Comment: _"Working code snippet cannot be created as of now as it is DB driven & the data is private."_ You should be able to create an example response to reproduce issue described at Question.